# django templatedoesnotexist current_date

Tags: django

I'm going through the Django Book. I'm in the middle of Chapter 4. I can't render my current_datetime.html template view. What am I doing wrong? It looks like the template loaders are not finding the right directory. http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/

I have created my templates directory in my project folder and current_datetime.html with in the directory.

```
Setting.py
import os.path

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
    # I've also tried: # '/Users/macuser/Python_Projects/django_test1/templates',
)

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_to_response('current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})

urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django_test1.views import hello, my_homepage_view, current_datetime, hours_ahead


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', my_homepage_view),
    (r'^hello/$', hello),
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),)
```

The error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /time/
current_datetime.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
current_datetime.html
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/macuser/Python_Projects/django_test1',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 23 Jul 2012 20:40:35 -0500
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/current_datetime.html (File does not exist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake. I did not create an actual app: python manage.py startapp "appName". I put "assert False" in the settings file and realized django was not even using my settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't checked render_to_Response format
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

Go through it, You need to add context_instance=RequestContext(request) to the response